# Convert JSON to Avro in Jmeter

Tags: json, apache-kafka, jmeter, performance-testing, avro

I need to convert a JSON message to Avro so that I can send it to Kafka.

I have the sample JSON request and also the schema from an avsc file for Avro.

Any ideas how I can do this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need:

1. To download [Avro Java libraries](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/avro/) and put them (along with the [dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)) to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. To restart JMeter to pick up the libraries
3. To add a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) with the relevant Groovy code to perform the conversion, a piece of example code is below:

   ```
   String schemaJson = 'your schema here'
   String genericRecordStr = 'your json payload here'
   def schemaParser = new org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser()
   def schema = schemaParser.parse(schemaJson)
   def decoderFactory = new org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory()
   def decoder = decoderFactory.jsonDecoder(schema, genericRecordStr)
   def reader = new org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader()(schema)
   def record = reader.read(null, decoder)
   ```
4. To send the message to Kafka, out of box JMeter doesn't support Kafka a couple of options are described in the [Apache Kafka - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter) article

Comment: Thank you, that was very useful. I have managed to get Jmeter sending basic messages to Kafka etc now. I'm still struggling a bit with the Avro serialisation part. How would you put the "record" in a Jmeter variable using vars.put please? I tried vars.put("myparam", record) but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "Avro", you are using the Schema Registry. If you're able to install the Kafka REST Proxy, you could send JSON events to it, then the proxy can be configured to integrate with the Registry to send Avro objects to the brokers

Or you can write a custom sampler, as linked in the other answer, but you'd swap the StringSerializer for an Avro Serializer implementation (you'd need to add that to the Jmeter classpath)